# Why does Bash return errors with `'ash` when defining a function?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a .bashrc file that has a very simple function like this

```
function module() {
    ....
}
```

I type "bash" on the command prompt and as expected the .bashrc gets executed however I get the error:

```
'ash: /user/.bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'ash: /user/.bashrc: line 1: `function module() {
```

I have tried removing the word "function" and I have also tried removing the `()` but none of this helps. Can someone let me know what is happening?

Bash version when I run `bash --version` is (I can upgrade to the latest version but ONLY the module will let me point to the latest bash so this problem has to be solved in this bash)

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: does the error start "ash" or "bash"

Comment: Strange enough it only says "ash"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I was using bash all the time but the .bashrc file was saved in Windows with the Windows CRs. Once I ran dos2unix it worked fine!

Comment: Yep, your error messages with characters overwriting the start of the line is the classic giveaway that you have `\r\n` line endings.